# Bootstrap navigation troubles - Responsive issues

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a website for a client and running into some issues. I have a fixed top and left menus and everything is working quite nicely in the mobile layout. However, when I'm on a desktop resolution and I hide the left menu, the navigation in the top menu seems to change to right justified (then when I shrink the resolution, the links drop down and the menu doubles in size). I made a div id for it but the only thing I'm really using is margin-left to give my search bar room.

Can anyone help me??? The website is: http://104.193.173.104/modx/index.php?id=1

Here is the code for my top menu:

```
<div id="main-navbar" class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">

<!-- Left menu toggle button -->
<button type="button" id="main-menu-toggle">
    <i class="navbar-icon fa fa-bars icon"></i>
</button>

<div class="navbar-inner">

    <div class="navbar-header">
        <div class="nav navbar-nav" style="">
            <!-- SEARCH BAR -->
            [[$searchBar]]
        </div>

        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-navbar-collapse">
            <i class="navbar-icon fa fa-bars"></i>
        </button>
    </div>

    <div id="main-navbar-collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse main-navbar-collapse">
        <div id="main-navigation-container">
            <!-- MAIN NAVIGATION -->
            [[Wayfinder? &startId=`8` &outerTpl=`outerTplTop` &innerTpl=`innerTplTop` &level=`2`]]

            <!-- LOGIN -->
            <div class="right clearfix">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right right-navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="dropdown-icon fa fa-sign-in"></i>&nbsp; Login</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS for the top nav container:

```
#main-navigation-container {
margin-left: 347px;
width: auto;
max-height: none;
}
```

I'm working with Bootstrap 3.3.6 and ModX Revo for my CMS.

Thanks in advance for any help! Let me know if you need me to provide any more code snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following CSS:

```
   .navbar-header{
    max-width: 200px;
    }
```

Comment: Wow, I have no idea how this worked, but it did! Just out of curiosity, how did you come up with 200px for the max width?

Comment: With the Chrome inspector I hovered over the white space you had and I saw that the navbar-header was taking over all the space and pushing all the buttons to the next line. Since the searchbar didn't need more than 200px I though about restricting it. I tested the code on my browser using the chrome inspector and it worked so I posted for you. 
Happy coding!

Comment: Awesome, thanks again for your help. I ended up changing it to 240 to match the width of the left panel. Cheers!